# Ant can't find Maven's "DependenciesTask"

Tags: java, maven, ant

I'm at a loss at what's wrong. I have an Ant build.xml that has the line

```
<path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
```

and then later

```
<target name="clean">
<artifact:mvn pom="${basedir}/pom.xml">
  <arg value="clean"/>
</artifact:mvn>
```

The error I get is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.setPathType(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

The .jar file exists in the Ant's lib/ folder, and it also contains said function (unzipped it and looked at .class file). Also, when I change the path in the "path=" attribute, it doesn't complain, which means it's not even looking!

Anyone have an idea why it's not even considering the "path=" element here? Strangely enough, for other people in my group it works, and it has for me too in the past (had to rebuild my machine and reinstall everything).

Comment: `path` is realtive to the basedir of `build.xml`. Moreover, consider the Maven Ant Tasks as dead, no one of us is maintaining them.

Comment: Oh. Is there a suggested replacement?

Comment: Either use Maven directly or Aether Ant Tasks, Use Ant's debug/verbose mode.